# Computational cost of enumerating graphlets in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In the paper [Efficient graphlet kernels for large graph comparison](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v5/shervashidze09a/shervashidze09a.pdf) (P. 489), it is mentioned that

> Since there are $\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\k\end{array}\right)$ size$-k$ subgraphs in a graph [with $n$ nodes], computing [vector $f_G$ of length $N_k$ whose i-th component corresponds to the frequency of occurrence of a particular graphlet in the graph] [...] requires $O(n^k)$ effort.

I understand that
$$\left(\begin{array}{l}n \\k\end{array}\right)=\frac{n !}{k !(n-k) !},$$
but where is the $O(n^k)$ coming from?

Comment: $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!} \leq n^k$, when $n >> k$, it asymptotically approaches $n^k$.